# Shoulda vs Remarkable for rspec and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I'm using rspec and cucumber for BBD.
Now I'm migrating to rails 3 and rspec 2 and as I could see both of frameworks (shoulda and remarkable) support rails 3 and rspec 2.

I have never used shoulda or remarkable.

What should I prefer to use with rspec: [shoulda](http://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda/tree/rails3) or [remarkable](http://github.com/remarkable/remarkable/tree/rspec2)? And why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think i would go for remarkable, since it is created especially for Rspec. Also it is extremely complete. Whereas Shoulda was created to get the rspec-style matchers inside Test::Unit.

Just my quick 2 cents.

[UPDATE] almost two years later, I am sorry to notice that remarkable is in a dreadful state. For rails 3.x you still have to use beta gems. I hope this will change or improve soon (unlikely), but for the moment I can only advise to use Shoulda.

Answer (score 3):

Just an update, since the Rails world moves so fast: Shoulda seems to have garnered three times as many watchers, two times as many forks, and one and half as many contributors. Remarkable's last commit was over a year ago, and shoulda's was within this month. That said the last 5 contributions were basically small bugs or minor touch ups.